# updating software list in redhat

Tags: linux, repository

What is the equivalent command for `sudo apt-get update` in redha/fedora/centost? I mean how can I refresh and download the list of softwares on the repository?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You really should have a look at `yum`'s [manpage](http://linux.die.net/man/8/yum). The commands to accomplish what you asked for are:

```
yum clean
yum makecache
```

Comment: http://linux.die.net/man/8/yum

Answer (score 2):

Yum refreshes its cached data automatically if it has been more than 90 minutes since the necessary data was last fetched. And it only downloads the needed data, instead of everything possible. So in general you don't need to do this manually.

If you really want to cache the data manually, use `yum clean all` followed by `yum makecache`.

Answer (score 1):

Yum refreshes its cache(s) automatically, the time a cache is considered valid is given in `/etc/yum.conf`, or much more commonly, in `/etc/yum.repos.d/` in each repository configuration (`expire_cache=`). To force *just* to revalidate caches and update next time `yum` is run, do `yum clean expire-cache`. The other `yum clean` subcommand relevant is `yum clean metadata` (delete all information on available packages).

Note that `ỳum clean all` does delete *all* data in the cache, forcing a full download the next time. This can take quite some time.

The gory details are in the manual pages for `yum(8)`.